# Retrieve linked servers out of system database files?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, system-tables, system-databases

I have the data and log files of a SQL-Server that has crashed. It's user databases have been restored. I am looking for the jobs and linked servers that have been there before the crash. I attached the old system databases and looked ad some views. Jobs have been found quickly in msdb. 
but sys.servers and sys.sysservers seem to query and display the current server always.

I tried:

```
select * from sys.servers 
select * from msdb_old.sys.servers 
select * from master_old.sys.servers
```

but all of them return the same, only the current server config.

Are the linked server objects persisted and queryable anywhere in the old files?

Comment: have you tried to fully qualify the sys.servers query "select * from oldmaster.sys.servers"

Comment: Yes. It does not matter if I query msdb_old, master_old ... the current Server configuration is always returned. Meanwhile I gave up and re-created the required servery manually.

Comment: The reason for this is because this is a view. Getting to the code of the view proves problematic at best but both of the views (current and old databases) are querying against the same data so the only way to get it would be to reverse engineer the view and this is just supposition but I'm guessing that this data is not kept in an area that was backed up.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't restore the system databases? As well, consider that even if you could access those underlying tables for a Link Server the password for the SQL Login configured is going to be encrypted. The method I have seen to decrypt  then won't work against a restored database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer placed here for future reference if needed. It looks as though this data may be in a hidden table in the master database sys schema named sysxsrvs.

According to what I could find this may be available to be queried if connected through the DAC.

It also uses sysobjvalues (contained in all databases). I believe to populate the srvproduct/providername fields.

reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179503.aspx